Can the versions of an effDated entity be eliminated in Guidewire?
I have an effDated entity that everytime a new register is created its historic is replicated in the last branch of the entity. So I have the new register and for example if the policy had 2 periods before the current period I have 3 registers, 2 versions and 1 "original" (from the latest period). I saw in code that these versions can be used with the AllVersions variable in the entity but I don't know if there is a way to delete (physical not logical) these registers.
I tried to set to null these registers but it didn't do anything like this:
effDatedEntity.AllVersions = null
I tried to remove one by one the versions but same as before:
effDatedEntity.AllVersions.each(\ elt -> elt.first() = null)
And I didn't see a method that I can use to remove the versions like you can do with the entities with the:
effDatedEntity.removeFromEffDatedEntity(thingToRemove)

No, there is no way to permanently remove an effdated entity instance that is part of an issued transaction.  This is by design to insure that all information relevant to the policy history is retained.
There is one exception and one alternative to this statement.
The exception is removal of PII information as required by GDPR and other regulations.  This is accomplished by following the instructions for "Configuring Personal Data Destruction" (requires login) in the product documentation.  For Policy data this will obfuscate to fulfill the requirements, not delete.
The alternative is to Archive the PolicyPeriod which will remove the data from the active database.  If there is no desire to ever restore the archived period then the archive image can be discarded.  Note that some information about the policy term being archived is retained but the bulk of the data is deleted from the active database.  More information on that is also in the product documentation (login required).

To tag on to Martin Aavik's excellent answer and add a bit more context, it's actually impossible to remove any effdated entities from the database, regardless of whether or not they exist on a bound policy. As Martin points out, bound effDated's cannot be updated in any way outside of archival or some edge cases around data privacy.
But you can remove them logically for unbound/non-quoted policies. PolicyCenter calls an policy "unlocked" if it's not bound or quoted. To remove these entities logically, you'd modify your code slightly as follows:
var bundle ... <- this is a read/write bundle, you can create your own or perhaps you have one in context already
    
effDatedEntity.AllVersions.each(\ elt -> {
    bundle.add(effDatedEntity.getSlice(elt.sliceDate)).remove()
})

This would effectively set the effDate to the expdate in the db, which makes it disappear in the app. It's how effDateds are soft deleted in InsuranceSuite. If you queried the db, you'd find it, but it'll never show in the application.
